# Azure CI/CD Pipeline with flask app unable to deploy through ZIP deploy

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, continuous-deployment

I'm unable to deploy my flask app to Azure Portal site. My build passes but my Deploy fails on the last step, trying to push the project on to the azure portals site. I'm using Azure portal to deploy there but wouldn't know what to look for to fix this issue. I am new to CI/CD builds. I have included the full yaml build (without some of the variables) and an image of the pipeline. If there is other information I need to post to get help let me know.

```yaml
  # Project root folder. Point to the folder containing manage.py file.
  projectRoot: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
  
  # Python version: 3.7
  pythonVersion: '3.7'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
      displayName: 'Use Python $(pythonVersion)'
    
    - script: |
        python -m venv antenv
        source antenv/bin/activate
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install setup
        pip install -r requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
      displayName: "Install requirements"

    - script: |
        source antenv/bin/activate
        python build.py
      workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
      displayName: "Download Weights and Models"

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(projectRoot)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      displayName: 'Upload package'
      artifact: drop
      
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeploymentJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: $(environmentName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          
          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
            displayName: 'Use Python version'

          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy Azure Web App : dl-sandbox'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureServiceConnectionId)
              appName: $(webAppName)
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above error could be caused by the app service's pricing tier being too small. You can try recreating your App Service with a higher pricing tier.

When Creating Web App, Choose **Change size** to choose a higher pricing tier in the Azure portal.

[image]

If above doesnot work out. You can check below steps to show more error messages and troubleshoot the issue.

To troubleshoot on the Azure app service:

> Go to Your Web App in Azure> App Service logs >turn on Detailed Error Messages.

To troubleshoot on Azure pipeline:

> Set the pipeline variable `system.debug=true`. Or check `Enable system diagnostics` when run your pipeline, See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops#configure-verbose-logs) for more information.

Comment: After looking at the size of the website which is about 1.5GB I think you are right since I am using the free 1GB plan. Also thank you for the troubleshooting information, I had no clue there were troubleshooting services.